# Is there any way I can do contract driven testing with ASP.NET 5?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dnx, coreclr

I have been doing contract driven testing with for my web apis with [this](https://github.com/SEEK-Jobs/pact-net) library. After migrating to .net core, I can't find a library that will enable me to do contract driven testing. And the library I was using is heavily dependent on nancy.

Anyone else came across this issue ?